# What this error is about, I'm not able to get it?

Tags: react-dropzone

> **TypeError: children is not a function**
>
> > (anonymous function) C:/Users/shravan/Documents/MERN stack/Courier App/client/node_modules/react-dropzone/dist/es/index.js:70

```
<Dropzone accept=".csv" onDropAccepted={this.onDrop.bind(this)}>        
              
          </Dropzone>
```

whats wrong with react-dropzone can anyone help

Comment: We have like 0 information to work on. Give us some code, some screenshots etc.

Comment: @NielsLucas see